How do I set Puppy Linux to persistent?
I have to use a rentable laptop for a few more days and they have some heavier restrictions for the Widows OS built-in so I can't install certain apps I need.
USB OSes work just fine. However, I cannot get Puppy Linux to not delete apps/files.
How do I set Puppy Linux to retain all installed applications/settings/Files upon shutdown?

how set are you on Puppy Linux? That seems to be a pretty restrictive choice; you could just as well install a regular Debian or Ubuntu to your USB drive. (and e.g. Ubuntu has a nice LIveUSB stick image with a "Persistence" option, as well)

Check this for other Linux distros https://www.linuxlookup.com/linux_iso

From https://puppylinux-woof-ce.github.io/install.html
Again, this will be a pristine system that requires you to save your session at shut down if you want to keep your settings.
Once saving the session is complete, a pupsave file or folder is created. On you next boot your files and settings will be exactly as you left them at last shutdown.
I believe it is in Setup->Shutdown

If you want to save your work at any time without shutting down, look for a Save icon on the desktop or use the terminal, check for this commands:
save2flash
snapmergepuppy
savepuppyd
This will save all the session data to your save file/folder immediately.
Creating a Puppy Save File
How Puppy Linux Save Works
A mod to save2flash + snapmergepuppy + savepuppyd
Bugfix for save2flash
Save2Flash --- Save Ram via SnapMergePuppy
Keep your savefile slim and healthy

You can save the session to a harddrive or an USB drive in a vfat, ntfs or linux partition. This will save all your settings to what is known as a pupsave file or folder. When you boot off the same media next time the pupsave will be found and all your files and settings will be as you left them.

